# Обелиски могут что-нито предварять?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> Обширные площади на пути к мавзолею теперь застроены жилыми
>   кварталами, через которые путь от пьяцца дель Пополо лежит
>   к Ватикану, но когда-то гигантские **подходы к усыпальнице
>   обожествленного предваряли два обелиска**.

Comment: У Даля значение слова связывалось со временем, но не с пространством. У Ушакова слово отправлено в книжно-устаревшие, так что это похоже на новоязовское словоупотребление. Осмыслить это можно, приняв единственное направление движения: шли мы туда, а потому обелиск "предварил" оказавшееся дальше и соотв. позже. Главное, что он не "преддверял" :)

Comment: Сашка, не шути со старенькой девушкой, к тому ж круглой сиротой!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могут **предварять,** то есть находиться **перед** подходами к усыпальнице.

Значение понятное: приставка ПРЕД обозначает и время, и пространство. В словарях оно не зафиксировано, но на практике осваивается, например:

Неподалеку располагался огромный рынок, его **предваряли** дешевые магазины, торгующие одеждой и обувью. [Наталья Александрова. Последний ученик да Винчи (2010)]